# iOS with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, sdk

I want to use the Facebook stuffs in my iPhone application.

Can anyone please guide me to achieve this.

I tried in Facebook developers website. But I felt tricky.

So please help to achieve this task with good and easy explanations.

(1) Create a Custom Facebook Login Box in my custom UI.

(2) and Authenticate it. And if its valid fetch the user data like profile name ,email id , and more data for the signed user.

(3) Please provide the helps .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even tried to read the Facebook documentation??, plus your question is not well formatted !!

Comment: Yes janacek, I read out the documentation. But I can't able get the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this sample [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) in github

Or you can use [SocialFramework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) provided by iOS. But it has limit like you can't customized it.

Comment: Yes Bhumeshwer,  Social Framework we can only post the data. But i want to use the signed user details.

Comment: Look into this site http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/facebook-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebook-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 2):

Just Login with your id and password to facebook developer account and download the sdk. in which you will get latest ios sdk with sample code.

[facebook ios sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/)

Comment: HI Himanshu, I download the latest sdk and trying to follow the guide through facebook docs. but i felt little tricky and not understand the concepts for my point of view (the facebook docs are good). I want only for the (1) User Login in my application. (2) And get the user data in the background and display it to another Xib. (3). That's it :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try integrating Parse Facebook Login Example. If you have not yet used Parse, it's a great easy to use and setup tool for getting api request analyticas, sending push notifications and other stuff app can use.

The company was bought by Facebook and they have a great documentation. Perhaps this might help you get started.

https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios